# JsonSchema conditional requirements in sub-object

Tags: jsonschema

This is the jsonschema I'm using:

```json
{
   "type":"object",
   "properties":{
      "a":{
         "type":"number",
         "minimum":1,
         "maximum":2
      },
      "b":{
         "type":"object",
         "properties":{
            "c":{"type": "number"}
         },
         "required":[
            "c"
         ],
         "additionalProperties":false
      }
   },
   "required":[
      "a",
      "b"
   ],
   "additionalProperties":false,
   "if":{
      "properties":{
         "a":{
            "const":1
         }
      }
   },
   "then":{
      "properties":{
         "b":{
            "d":{"type":"number"},
            "required":[
               "c",
               "d"
            ]
         }
      }
   },
   "else":{
       "properties":{
         "b":{
            "e":{"type":"number"},
            "required":[
               "c",
               "e"
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

as far as I understand, this should match objects like:

```json
{
    "a": 1,
    "b": {
        "c": 1,
        "d": 1,
    },
}
```

or

```json
{
    "a": 2,
    "b": {
        "c": 1,
        "e": 1,
    },
}
```

and fail objects like:

```json
{
    "a": 2,
    "b": {
        "c": 1,
        "d": 1,
    },
}
```

However, when I plug the first example in https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/, it fails with the message `Property 'd' has not been defined and the schema does not allow additional properties`.

Is this not defined by the if?

For some reason, stackoverflow doesn't let me post questions with huge jsonschemas and only a small bit of text, so here's some lorem ipsum:

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed quis odio id sapien congue malesuada sed mollis nisi. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Maecenas ultrices tempus risus, ac eleifend sapien finibus at. Vestibulum tincidunt sapien in lectus commodo accumsan. Nulla dolor mi, pretium non erat at, convallis malesuada nisl. Mauris sed leo quis turpis convallis sollicitudin eget non eros.

Vestibulum quis urna vitae ante tincidunt varius. Curabitur magna nisi, semper vitae finibus a, dignissim venenatis metus. Etiam eget mollis quam. Quisque aliquet tempus dui, eu vestibulum sapien ornare sed. Ut ut est enim. Etiam placerat elementum dui, nec maximus urna efficitur ut. Phasellus nulla sapien, posuere eu rhoncus vel, semper eu ante. Praesent sagittis elit et faucibus elementum. Mauris bibendum consequat mauris, a tincidunt enim vestibulum ac. Sed sagittis interdum bibendum. Donec eu dolor vestibulum, congue ex a, finibus lacus. Pellentesque aliquam bibendum fringilla. Donec neque arcu, sagittis ut est nec, fringilla sagittis arcu. Morbi sed ex quam. Nulla cursus, magna in rhoncus vestibulum, diam magna imperdiet metus, at sollicitudin mauris lorem tempor purus. Ut finibus commodo ipsum, eget malesuada mauris accumsan sed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. The problem was twofold:

1. The properties from the nested object should have been wrapped in a `properties` key
2. If/Then only work if the original schema also applies, so `additionalProperties` should be set to `true` there, and set to false in all of the subschemas

The correct jsonschema is seen below and behaves as expected:

```json
{
   "type":"object",
   "properties":{
      "a":{
         "type":"number",
         "minimum":1,
         "maximum":2
      },
      "b":{
         "type":"object",
         "properties":{
            "c":{"type": "number"}
         },
         "required":[
            "c"
         ],
      }
   },
   "required":[
      "a",
      "b"
   ],
   "additionalProperties":false,
   "if":{
      "properties":{
         "a":{
            "const":1
         }
      }
   },
   "then":{
      "properties":{
         "b":{
            "properties": {
               "c":{"type": "number"},
               "d":{"type": "number"},
            },
            "required":[
               "c",
               "d"
            ],
            "additionalProperties":false
         }
      }
   },
   "else":{
       "properties":{
         "b":{
            "properties": {
               "c":{"type": "number"},
               "e":{"type": "number"},
            },
            "required":[
               "c",
               "e"
            ],
            "additionalProperties":false
         }
      }
   }
}
```